# same package, different directories

Tags: java, package, classpath, runtime-error, noclassdeffounderror

In my `proj3` directory, I have a folder `gui` and a folder `foo`.
The files in `gui` belong to the `package foo`.
Using gmake, everything compiles file, but when I try to execute `java foo.Main` (main method) in `foo` which calls `gui.Display`, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: foo/Display
 at foo.Main.main(Main.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foo.Display
```

I am compiling from the proj3 directory. I added `./gui/` to my `CLASSPATH` which now has `.:./gui/` among other utile.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you `import` the needed class?

Comment: `java foo.Main`  For that to find `Main`, are you executing the `java` command from `foo` directory?

Comment: @user1870638 ``Display`` belongs to the same package, so I shouldn't need an import, I think. Having one there doesn't fix the problem either, unfortunately.

@AndrewThompson ``Main`` is a class in ``package foo`` which has the ``main`` method. To run my program, in the terminal from the proj3 directory, I enter: ``java foo.Main`` (I don't believe ``foo.Main`` would work from inside the ``foo`` directory.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files in gui belong to the package **foo**. The files should be moved into folder **foo** as well.

Comment: They do exist in a folder ``gui``. I have the folder ``gui`` at the same level as the folder ``foo``. I tried having ``gui`` inside ``foo`` but that didn't work any better.

Comment: *"but that didn't work any better."*  What ***exact*** error did you get in that case?  If the source files are in the same package, it is easiest to store them in the **same** directory.

Comment: Well I'm certain if I had the exact files in the ``foo`` folder, it would, of course, work. When I meant "did't work" any better, that was with having the entire folder ``gui`` in ``foo``. I actually get the same exact error.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to have some sort of separation between the ``gui`` files and the ``foo`` files (like a folder). But the ``gui`` files still need to belong to the ``package foo.``

Answer (score 0):

move gui.Display to the package foo

Comment: gui.Display does belong to the package foo. It will certainly work if I move the file gui.Display into the foo folder, but I want some sort of separation.